# Why my function in .vimrc got called automatically?

Tags: function, vim

As I know, we could define function in .vimrc as below:

```
function Fun()
    do something here
endfunction
```

Then we could call it like `:call Fun()`.

For one of my system, **there's only the function definition in my .vimrc, however the function is always exectued once I get into vim. Why?**

Below is version of my vim:

```
# vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Feb 17 2012 10:24:10)
Included patches: 1-411
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic -autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms -byte_offset -cindent 
-clientserver -clipboard -cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist -cmdline_info -comments 
-cryptv -cscope -cursorshape -dialog -diff -digraphs -dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags 
-eval -ex_extra -extra_search -farsi -file_in_path -find_in_path -float 
-folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv -insert_expand +jumplist
 -keymap -langmap -libcall -linebreak -lispindent -listcmds -localmap -menu 
-mksession -modify_fname -mouse -mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm 
-mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse -mouse_xterm +multi_byte -multi_lang -mzscheme 
-netbeans_intg -osfiletype -path_extra -perl -printer -profile -python 
-quickfix -reltime -rightleft -ruby -scrollbind -signs -smartindent -sniff 
-startuptime -statusline -sun_workshop -syntax -tag_binary -tag_old_static 
-tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo -termresponse -textobjects -title -toolbar 
-user_commands -vertsplit -virtualedit +visual -visualextra -viminfo -vreplace 
+wildignore -wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp 
-xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "/etc/virc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall  -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1        
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim       -lm  -lselinux -lncurses -lacl
```

And my .vimrc:

```
# cat ~/.vimrc
function Fun1()
        :!ls
endfunction
```

Function name doesn't matter, I've changed the name as a test.

**Update on July 8, 2015:**

According to the answer from Ben, and since I'd like my .vimrc be compatible over multiple environments, I wrap the function definition with `if has('eval')...endif` as my finial solution:

```
if has('eval')
    function! Fun1()
        do something
    endfunction
endif
```

Comment: @lcd047, Yes..It's the vim installed in my production. I have no choice on it.

Comment: Are you somewhere remapping it like nnoremap ls :call Fun1() or something? It shouldnt' be running automatically, maybe you can post any other relevant parts of your vimrc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your vim is compiled without "eval" support. That means your Vim does not support defining functions. The opening `function Fun1()` command is therefore invalid, and ignored. Then the function definition is executed because those *are* valid commands.

You will need to install a more fully-featured Vim, or compile your own Vim, or find an alternate Vim installation on your system that has more features. "eval" comes with a NORMAL or larger feature set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and since I'd like this .vimrc be compatible over multiple environments, I will wrap my function with `if has('eval')...endif`.